# Can not load gems and files under lib dir for testing case in netbeans ruby project

Tags: ruby, netbeans

I create a **ruby project** in netbeans 6.9.1, and wrote some source ruby files under lib dir, then wrote test cases under test dir. But when i right click the test case file and choose 'Test File', error occurs, the test file can not load the ruby source file under lib dir and gems even though i required them. i printed $LOAD_PATH, it really doesn't load the lib source files and gems.

Could someone help me on how to resolve the problem in netbeans? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved.
one is to add -I option, the other is related to Log4r::INFO